Question about proof, using contrapositive, of Lamé’s theorem
Given the following lemma: If $a > b \geq 1$ and the call EUCLID(a, b) performs $k \geq 1$ recursive calls, then $a \geq F_{k+2}$ and $b \geq F_{k+1}$, which can be proved by induction, how is the following theorem an immediate corollary：
Lamé’s theorem: For any integer $k \geq 1$, if $a > b \geq 1$ and $b < F_{k + 1}$, then the call EUCLID(a, b) makes fewer than $k$ recursive call.
EUCLID refers to the standard Euclid’s algorithm for calculating the GCD and $F_{k}$ refers to the kth Fibonacci number
This theorem appears to be the contrapositive of the above lemma, with the exception of the claim of “making fewer than $k$ calls.” So my question: is the theorem the contrapositive of the lemma? If not, how is the theorem an immediate corollary of the lemma?

So Euclid's algorithm always terminates. The lemma tells you that if it takes $k$ steps to terminate, then $b\geq F_{k+1}$. It is not difficult to see that at each iteration of $EUCLID(x,y)$ the values of $x$ and $y$ do not increase. Therefore, if you take strictly more than $k$ steps, you will also necessarily have that $b\geq F_{k+1}$. So the theorem is indeed just contraposition.
